# position the buttons next to each other

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my code and I've tried many ways to set the buttons next to each other but they didn't work.

I would really apprciate your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please do it android:orientation="horizontal"

Comment: This can't be answered unless you define 'next to' more precisely

Comment: well what all do u have in your layout and what all you need to align side by side?

Answer (score 2):

change android:orientation="vertical" to android:orientation="horizontal"

Comment: I know this way but it doesn't work since I have text fields and text views

Comment: Oh it's ok thank you I just seperated the two buttons with a linear layout :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through by changing android:orientation="vertical" to android:orientation="horizontal". If you post a pattern of your UI then i can help you more precisely, thanks.